# How to get a parameterized ExecutorService?

Tags: java, generics, types, concurrency, executorservice

How can I get an `ExecutorService` instance with a specific type parameter?

I have a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` named `service` and I'm calling its [`submit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) method with a parameterized `Callable` to get a `Future` for the result generated by the `Callable`.

`void doSomething(Callable<Response> callback) {
    Future<Response> futureResponse = service.submit(callback);
}`

It works ok, but `service` is not-parameterized; ideally it would be (i.e., `ExecutorService<Response>`). I'm currently creating the executor service with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)`, which doesn't appear to have any way to parameterize the call. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: `ExecutorService` is not a generic type, so you can't. Why do you want to?

Comment: The method `submit` is already parameterized, so it returns a `Future` with the same type argument as the `Callable` you pass to it.

Comment: @Oleg , @Radiodef - Thanks, you're both right. I was misreading the docs. Seeing the type parameter on the `submit` method, I was assuming it was the entire ExecutorService that was parameterized, but I see now that it's the `submit` method specifically. Which explains why I wasn't getting any warnings from the code above.